# Controller is unable to map the object and bring the list result

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

This is my Controller, I want to list of the books but it returns the error below:

> book is not mapped

```java
@RestController
public class BookController {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;


    @Transactional
    @PostMapping("/books")
    public String save(@RequestBody @Valid BookInDto request){

        Book book = request.toModel(manager);
        manager.persist(book);
        return book.toString();
    }

    @GetMapping("/books")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<BookOutDto> bookList(){
        return manager.createQuery("from book", Book.class)
                .getResultStream()
                .map(BookOutDto::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you mapping /books twice ?

Comment: @Dren one `/books` is mapped as GET and the other is mapped as POST.